# Exclude Multiple Post Thumbnails From Post Attachments

Tags: thumbnails

i am trying to exclude multiple post thumbnails from attachments.

i have the following thumbnails setup in my functions.php:

```
$thumb = new MultiPostThumbnails(array(
    'label' => 'Client Logo',
    'id' => 'client-logo',
    'post_type' => 'clients'
    )
);

$thumb = new MultiPostThumbnails(array(
    'label' => 'Portfolio Home Image',
    'id' => 'port-home-image',
    'post_type' => 'clients'
    )
);

$thumb = new MultiPostThumbnails(array(
    'label' => 'Home Slide Image',
    'id' => 'home-slide-image',
    'post_type' => 'clients'
    )
);
```

i then have the following code, within the loop to pull in all image attachements and disaply them

```
<?php
      $thumb_id = get_post_thumbnail_id( $post_id );
      $args = array(
      'post_type' => 'attachment',
      'numberposts' => $nimg,
      'post_mime_type' => 'image',
      'post_status' => null,
      'post_parent' => $post->ID,
      'exclude' => $thumb_id
      );
      $attachments = get_posts($args);
      if ($attachments) {
      foreach ($attachments as $attachment) {
      //echo apply_filters('the_title', $attachment->post_title);
      echo wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment->ID, array (650,650));

     }
      }

?>
```

this line: `$thumb_id = get_post_thumbnail_id( $post_id );` excludes the featured post thumbnail.

any ideas on how i can exclude my 3 other thumbnails?

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks Danyo

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/multiple-post-thumbnails

Answer (score 1):

```
     $thumb_id = get_post_thumbnail_id(get_the_ID());
     $bg_id = MultiPostThumbnails::get_post_thumbnail_id('work', 'background-image', $post->ID);
     $args = array(
       'post_type' => 'attachment',
       'numberposts' => -1,
       'post_status' => null,
       'post_parent' => $post->ID,
       'exclude' => array($thumb_id, $bg_id)

      );
```

Answer (score 0):

I've only modified the 'exclude' line. It's not tested but it should work.

```
<?php
      $thumb_id = get_post_thumbnail_id( $post_id );
      $args = array(
      'post_type' => 'attachment',
      'numberposts' => $nimg,
      'post_mime_type' => 'image',
      'post_status' => null,
      'post_parent' => $post->ID,
      'exclude' => $thumb_id, MultiPostThumbnails::get_post_thumbnail_id('clients', 'client-logo', $post_id), MultiPostThumbnails::get_post_thumbnail_id('clients', 'port-home-image', $post_id), MultiPostThumbnails::get_post_thumbnail_id('clients', 'home-slide-image', $post_id)
      );
      $attachments = get_posts($args);
      if ($attachments) {
      foreach ($attachments as $attachment) {
      //echo apply_filters('the_title', $attachment->post_title);
      echo wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment->ID, array (650,650));

     }
      }

?>
```

Comment: thanks for the response, unfortunately is doesnt seem to work? still including those images

Comment: Can you tell me what this line returns? `MultiPostThumbnails::get_post_thumbnail_id('clients', 'client-logo', $post_id)`

Comment: Thanks, but this line still doesnt remove the desired image..